# emacs directory variables excluding particular subdir

Tags: emacs, directory, project, indentation, subdirectory

I have a project A which requires 2 spaces indentation, but it embeds another project in a subfolder B which uses 4 spaces.

I have the following in A/.dir-locals.el:

```
((c-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
            (c-basic-offset . 2))))
```

... and it nicely applies to all c files in directory A.

Question: Can I in that same dir-locals.el file exclude the subfolder B from being affected by the 2 spaces indentation?

I could of cause create a A/B/.dir-locals.el with the settings for B, but since it is A that is the exception right now, I would prefer to keep the setup in A/.dir-locals.el

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the manual:

```
   Here’s an example of a ‘.dir-locals.el’ file:

     ((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
              (fill-column . 80)))
      (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")
                 (subdirs . nil)))
      ("src/imported"
       . ((nil . ((change-log-default-name
                   . "ChangeLog.local"))))))

This sets ‘indent-tabs-mode’ and ‘fill-column’ for any file in the
directory tree, and the indentation style for any C source file.  The
special ‘subdirs’ element is not a variable, but a special keyword which
indicates that the C mode settings are only to be applied in the current
directory, not in any subdirectories.  Finally, it specifies a different
‘ChangeLog’ file name for any file in the ‘src/imported’ subdirectory.
```

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Directory Variables` <kbd>RET</kbd>

So in your case, you might be looking for something like:

```
((c-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)
            (c-basic-offset . 2)))
 ("B" . ((c-mode . ((c-basic-offset . 4))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify paths in `.dir-locals` files.

I think [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) is a better solution anyway. Because it allows you to share coding styles with users of other editors. Emacs has a nice [package](https://melpa.org/#/editorconfig) to apply the settings of a `.editorconfig` file.

Place this in your `A` directory:

```
# top-most EditorConfig file

root = true
# only match files in root folder
[/*.c]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

Comment: According to the manual .dir-locals does support subdirectories and the question was specifically about subdirectories in .dir-locals. Good to bring up editorconfig, though.